# Creating a variance column for financials in DAX (credits/debits) with the correct sign

Tags: dax

I have revenue data that has a natural credit balance (less than zero or negative) and expense data that has a natural debit balance (greater than zero or positive).  Revenue accounts are tagged as reporting `code=400` and all other items are some other number other than `400`.

I would like to create a variance column between two measures where the idea is to display whether it is favorable to profit or not.  Creating the two measures is not the problem...it is that the variance calculation itself is different for revenue than expenses.  `Current-LastPeriod=Variance` will work for Revenue, while `(Current-LastPeriod)*-1=Variance` will work for Expenses.

How can I construct a DAX calculation that handles this type of situation?

I tried IF statements but received an error saying a single value for my reportingcodeid column could not be determined.  It makes sense as it is a measure.  Here is what I tried.

```
Variance:=IF(TrialBalance_View[ReportingCode1ID]=400,[MonthlyAmount]-[MonthlyAmount_PY],[MonthlyAmount]-[MonthlyAmount_PY]*-1)
```

This is an issue I am sure a lot of Finance/Accounting people have and I appreciate any help I can get!  Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing your data model and code of the measures, I suggest this approach:

```
Variance = 
SUMX(
   VALUES(TrialBalance_View[ReportingCode1ID]),
   VAR Account_Variance = [MonthlyAmount]-[MonthlyAmount_PY]
   RETURN IF(TrialBalance_View[ReportingCode1ID] = 400, Account_Variance, -Account_Variance)
)
```

Here, we first create a list of reporting codes visible in a current context using VALUES function. Then, SUMX iterates these codes one by one. For each code, it computes variance and stores it in a variable. Then, if code is 400, it takes variance, else it takes negative variance.

If it does not work, please add your data model diagram, and post DAX code for your measures.

Comment: This is great, while not the exact same problem, this method helped me solve my issue with variance day to day.  Just needed to use the VALUES for each date to store the difference between Prior Day and Current Day!